# using INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'MONTH') in SUBPARTITION

Tags: oracle, plsql, intervals, partitioning

I'm trying to add partitions to a table I created. I want it partitioned on "PARTITION GRP" and subpartitioned by month. But I don't know how to write the INTERVAL clause inside a subpartition. 
Can someone help me on this? thanks!

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_GRP)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (RPTG_MTH_DATE)
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))
(
   PARTITION PG_0 VALUES LESS THAN (1)
  (SUBPARTITION PG_0_201401 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))),
   PARTITION PG_1 VALUES LESS THAN (2)
  (SUBPARTITION PG_1_201401 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))),   
   PARTITION PG_2 VALUES LESS THAN (3)
  (SUBPARTITION PG_2_201401 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))),
   PARTITION PG_3 VALUES LESS THAN (4)
  (SUBPARTITION PG_3_201401 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))),
   PARTITION PG_4 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
  (SUBPARTITION PG_4_201401 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
 )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54559):

> **Restrictions on Interval Partitioning**
>   The INTERVAL clause is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - You can specify only one partitioning key column, and it must be of NUMBER or DATE type.
> - This clause is not supported for index-organized tables.
> - You cannot create a domain index on an interval-partitioned table.
> - Interval partitioning is not supported at the subpartition level.
>     ...

So you can't have interval subpartitioning.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess I have to manually add subpartitions to each partition, but does this mean I have to remember to add a new subpartition as a new month comes in?

Comment: If you use subpartitions you'll have to add new partitions and/or subpartitions manually. I strongly recommend that you set the table up so it's interval partitioned so that the database can add needed partitions on an as-needed basis.

Comment: The challenge I'm facing right now is I need to insert each component to this table separately at different time, and the only way I know is to use ALTER TABLE TRUNCATE PARTITION. I used to use "PARTITION_GRP" as the subpartition so that I can do interval partition, but it seems I have to list all the subpartitions within each partition to completely truncate a "PARTITION_GRP". That's why I was thinking maybe I could switch these two...