# How to create Day and Hourly partitioning in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle-11G database.

I am trying to create **day** wise partition and again **sub-partition on hourly** level.

Below is the script I am using

```
CREATE TABLE test_shipments
( order_date    DATE NOT NULL
, delivery_date DATE NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (order_date)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day'))
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (order_date)
( PARTITION p_2006_jul VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2006-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
  ( SUBPARTITION p06_jul_e1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2006-08-01 12:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')) 
  ,SUBPARTITION p06_jul_e2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2006-08-01 13:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')) 
  ,SUBPARTITION p06_jul_e3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2006-08-01 14:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')) 
  )
  );
```

***I am expecting to have partition for every day and again sub-partition for every hour in that day.*** The above script creates partition per day only. Hourly sub-partition is not getting created. Can anyone please guide?

Comment: You [can't do interval subpartitoning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26808000/266304); do you plan to create new subpartitions manually for every day? Are the partitions and subpartitions supposed to be on different columns?

Comment: No, it is on the same column (order_date). I will change that in my example. It shouldn't be a manual operation. I want it to be created dynamically. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just partition by hourly intervals?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you not create simple partition by Hourly range? Example: `PARTITION BY RANGE (order_date) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' HOUR)`

Anyway, this one works. However, you should use `TIMESTAMP` data type instead of `DATE`. For hour value you have to create a virtual column.

```
CREATE TABLE test_shipments (
   order_date    TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
   order_date_hour NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM order_date)), 
   delivery_date DATE NOT NULL)
PARTITION BY RANGE (order_date)
INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (order_date_hour)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
  (SUBPARTITION HOUR00 VALUES (0),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR01 VALUES (1),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR02 VALUES (2),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR03 VALUES (3),
   ...
   SUBPARTITION HOUR22 VALUES (22),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR23 VALUES (23)   
  )
(  
  PARTITION P_20150101 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP'2015-01-01 00:00:00')  
);
```

If you are enforced to use `DATE` data type you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_shipments (
   order_date    DATE NOT NULL,
   order_date_hour NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(order_date, 'HH24')), 
   delivery_date DATE NOT NULL)
PARTITION BY RANGE (order_date)
INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (order_date_hour)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
  (SUBPARTITION HOUR00 VALUES (0),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR01 VALUES (1),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR02 VALUES (2),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR03 VALUES (3),
   ...
   SUBPARTITION HOUR22 VALUES (22),
   SUBPARTITION HOUR23 VALUES (23)   
  )
(  
  PARTITION P_20150101 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2015-01-01')  
);
```

Maybe you want to group night time hours:

```
(
SUBPARTITION HOUR_NIGHT VALUES (0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 19,20,21,22,23),
SUBPARTITION HOUR07 VALUES (7),
SUBPARTITION HOUR08 VALUES (8),
SUBPARTITION HOUR11 VALUES (11),
...
SUBPARTITION HOUR17 VALUES (17),
SUBPARTITION HOUR18 VALUES (18)
)
```

Comment: Curious why would a timestamp be better than a date? Can you please provide a brief explanation for my academic purposes. Thanks in advance for your expertise and patience

Comment: 5 years ago. I think you can simply exchange them according to your personal preferences. `INTERVAL '1' DAY` works only with `TIMESTAMP`, there will be some implicit casts

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit got it. Thanks for your response and sharing your knowledge